# lxml unicode characters

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

I'm new to lxml and python. I'm trying to parse an html document. When I parse using the standard xml parser it will write the characters out correctly but I think it fails to parse as I have trouble searching it with xpath.

Example file being parsed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="demo">Garbléd charactérs</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Parsing code:

```
from lxml import etree

fname = 'output/so-help.html'

# parse
hparser = etree.HTMLParser()
htree   = etree.parse(fname, hparser)

# garbled
htree.write('so-dumpu.html', encoding='utf-8')

# targets
demo_name = htree.xpath("//span[@id='demo']")

# garbled
print 'name: "' + demo_name[0].text
```

Terminal output:

```
name: "GarblÃ©d charactÃ©rs
```

htree.write output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>title</title></head><body>
    <span id="demo">GarblÃ©d charactÃ©rs</span>
</body></html>
```

Comment: If you change the output encoding from `utf-8` to `latin1`, what do you get?

Comment: I get the correct output! Now I tried overriding the parser encoding `hparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='latin1')` but my xpath result still prints garbled. Ideas for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem was that you tried to encode an already encoded data, what you need is to let 
parser decode the data with utf-8.
* in your original code try demo_name[0].text.decode('utf-8') and you will see

the right way to do it :

```
from lxml import etree

fname = 'output/so-help.html'

# parse
hparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
htree   = etree.parse(fname, hparser)

# garbled
htree.write('so-dumpu.html')

# targets
demo_name = htree.xpath("//span[@id='demo']")

# garbled
print 'name: "' + demo_name[0].text
```

Comment: I don't yet understand why this works. `hparser = etree.HTMLParser()` followed by `print htree.docinfo.encoding` yields `UTF-8` with garbled text. `hparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')` followed by `print htree.docinfo.encoding` also yields `UTF-8` but with clean text. How is that?

Comment: I think that the docinfo.encoding is the encoding from the document header, while the encoding that you pass to parser is the one for actually decoding the text.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the output encoding:

```
htree.write('so-dumpu.html', encoding='latin1')
```

and

```
print 'name: "' + demo_name[0].text.encode('latin1')
```

Comment: Almost there. `.decode` throws this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128)`. The HTMLParser's detected encoding is UTF8. Detected UTF-8 plus overridden latin1 encoding spits out the garbled text/exception using `.decode`

Comment: this can be the worst kind of wrong, the accidental right :) you are encoding with latin1 what was already encoded with parser default.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your XHTML document is encoded in utf-8. The issue is that the encoding is not specified in the HTML document. By default, browsers and lxml.html assume HTML documents are encoded in ISO-8859-1, that's why your document is incorrectly parsed. If you open it in your browser, it will also be displayed incorrectly.

You can specify the encoding of your document like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

You can force the encoding used by lxml this way (like your can change the encoding used in your browser) :

```
file = open(fname)
filecontents = file.read()
filecontents = filecontents.decode("utf-8")
htree = lxml.html.fromstring(filecontents)
print htree.xpath("//span[@id='demo']")[0].text
```

Comment: You could also use hparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8') to force lxml to use utf-8